# Bootstrap form dropdowns buttons

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

How to create a drop-down button from select form using Bootstrap 3.

```
<div class="input-group">
  <form>
    <input type="text"  name="search" class="form-control">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
    <select class="form-control" name="my_list">
      <option value="one">One</option>
      <option value="two">Two</option>
      <option value="three">Three</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"> GO</button>
    </span>
  </form>
</div>![ See image below for intended look][2]
```

[image]

Comment: In what way is your current code not working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-buttons-dropdowns

```
  <div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="...">
  <div class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Action <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div><!-- /btn-group -->
</div><!-- /input-group -->
```

Comment: That's the way to go.. Also, you can get the red button just by changing the `btn-default` class to `btn-danger`. (Assuming you are using the default Bootstrap theme)

Comment: should i use <li> instead of the <option value="one">? How will it submit the form post?

Comment: you can make a script which would change input value in form on click at <li>

Comment: DO you have a JavaScript sample to "change input value in form on click at <li>"
Here is my the code: http://jsfiddle.net/webtest/4n1pasvt/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4n1pasvt/6/ - value taken from attribute `data-action` and then submitting the form

Comment: On **your example - http://jsfiddle.net/4n1pasvt/6/**. I do not see the form working. I was expecting to form to submit to google.

Comment: It is just front-end, if you want form to do something - do it yourself

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76480/discussion-between-user2711365-and--).